# How to Show or Hidden Categories on page in Wordpress?

Tags: categories

I have a problem to resolve. I have wordpress site with 2 pages : Food and Cooking.

I have categories : food_categories (1) and cooking_categories (2).

I want to show only food_categories  on Food page and only cooking_categories on Cooking page.

Please help me to resolve it . Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Goto your respective page template file, default is page.php and the following code

```
<?php
    if (is_page('Food')) {
      $catID=11;
    } elseif (is_page('Cooking')) {
      $catID=12;
    }
?>
```

To get the category ID, navigate to dashboard>posts>categories>

Click on the respective category, and see the url,
it must be something like this `wp-admin/categories.php?action=edit&cat_ID=11`

take the value of `cat_ID` in this case the id will be

Comment: @Nguyen ngo  if you got the solution then please mark this as answer